# Android Network Discovery: "Notification for a listener that is no longer active"

Tags: android, android-networking

I'm using Android's "network discovery" API (NsdManager, etc). Things work fine, for some time. At some point, the client begins failing, and I see this in the logs,

```
D/NsdService(  894): Notification for a listener that is no longer active: 129
E/NsdService(  894): Unhandled { when=-3ms what=393242 obj=com.android.server.NsdService$NativeEvent@420fb588 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
D/NsdService(  894): Notification for a listener that is no longer active: 129
E/NsdService(  894): Unhandled { when=-3ms what=393242 obj=com.android.server.NsdService$NativeEvent@421c1ec8 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
D/NsdService(  894): Notification for a listener that is no longer active: 129
E/NsdService(  894): Unhandled { when=0 what=393242 obj=com.android.server.NsdService$NativeEvent@422f8a28 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
```

Nothing can get me out of this state other than rebooting the device (really). Not even killing the client process.

Of course, the above messages could be a red herring. I don't have any evidence that they are related to the discovery failure.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have received this for some time now.

Comment: I did not. Upvote the question if you want more eyes on it.